# getaddrinfo() thread failed to start while building docker image

Tags: node.js, docker, curl

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM linuxserver/code-server:latest
 
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash - &&\
    apt-get install -y nodejs
```

I run the build command

```
docker build -t node-ide .
```

On the local computer (Windows 11) and it works fine.
But when I upload it to ubuntu server and run the same, I get an error

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/2 : FROM linuxserver/code-server:latest
 ---> 997b7b90cb65
Step 2/2 : RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash - &&    apt-get install -y nodejs
 ---> Running in d0ec2365c9d1
curl: (6) getaddrinfo() thread failed to start
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package nodejs
The command '/bin/sh -c curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash - &&    apt-get install -y nodejs' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: I run similar error when the host OS version is incompatible with the OS version of base image.  If it's not seems network issue, you can try to check the host and base image OS version. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405417/20-04-vs-22-04-inside-docker-with-a-16-04-host-thread-start-failures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment of @yong, I downgraded, now it works like this:

```
FROM linuxserver/code-server:4.4.0-ls125
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash - &&\
    sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Answer (score 13):

Me helped option `--security-opt seccomp=unconfined` for docker run

```
sudo docker run -it --security-opt seccomp=unconfined ubuntu
```

For docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  example:
    build: .
    security_opt:
      - seccomp:unconfined
```

Comment: The question was about docker build, not docker run

Comment: Perhaps not the answer for the question, but definitely answered the one I had

Comment: This is the answer you need if you're facing a CURL issue inside your docker container, took couple of hours for me to get this resolved,  even chatGPT couldnt guide me in the correct path

Answer (score 9):

This is very likely due to a mismatch of the `glibc` lib used in your docker image, expecting the syscall `clone(3)` to be allowed, while your Docker engine (on the host) doesn't allow it.

https://github.com/adoptium/containers/issues/215#issuecomment-1142046045

Answer (score 2):

In my case I used python 3.8 in several dockerfiles and there was the same error. I fixed it by specifying more accurate version because of some new official image updates.

```
FROM python:3.8
```

to

```
FROM python:3.8.15
```

Answer (score 0):

It's seems a network issue, you can use 'ping deb.nodesource.com' command to test it.

Comment: There is no network problem, the network connection works